# Transfering Photoshop paths separately

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path

[image: paths collapse]
No matter how I move multiple paths from one image to another (dragging, copy-pasting), they keep collapsing into single path (see pic). Is there a way to copy/move them and keep the original structure?

Comment: Not certain what your issue it. I can [highlight multiple paths in the Paths Panel then drag them to a new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAD5j.gif) and they are still separate paths.

Comment: Thank you so much for this gif. I got it now. I had empty path in second image, so all initial paths would collapse into it. If there are no paths in second image, all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what your issue may be. I can highlight multiple paths in the Paths Panel then drag them to a new image and they are still separate paths.

[image]